# Laravel Illuminate Contracts Select Max Among Distinct

Tags: php, laravel, contract

I have an existing query that allows an array or single number passed in for parcel_year. I would like to select the max value of parcel_year for distinct values of existing fields selected. Three of the four fields are expected to not change year by year but owners may. If I pass in years 2019 and 2020 I'd like the query to return only 2020 if the fields are the same in both years. If there are different values for owners, I'd like both rows to be returned with their corresponding parcel_year. Adding parcel_year to my select causes two rows to return rather than one as expected by the nature of select distinct.

'''

```
/**
 * Get parcels that match a given search query.
 *
 * The search query can contain an owner name or a property address.
 * If the query is empty, all parcels are returned.
 *
 * @param  string                                               $searchQuery The search query.
 * @param  mixed                                                $year        The year of the information to search,
 *                                                                           or an array of years.
 *                                                                           Only distinct results will be returned.
 * @param  int                                                  $page        The page of results to get.
 * @param  int                                                  $per_page    How many results per page.
 * @return Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator              Parcels that match the search query.
 */
public function searchParcels($searchQuery, $year, $page, $per_page = 20)
{
    $searchQueryNoSpaces = str_replace(' ', '', $searchQuery);

    $parcels = Parcel::
        select('complete_parcel_number', 'owners', 'full_site_address', 'class_code')
        ->distinct()
        ->year($year)
        ->active()
        ->where(function ($query) use ($searchQueryNoSpaces) {
            $query
                ->whereRaw(
                    "REPLACE(owners, ' ', '') LIKE ?",
                    [
                        "%$searchQueryNoSpaces%"
                    ]
                )
                ->orWhereRaw(
                    "REPLACE(full_site_address, ' ', '') LIKE ?",
                    [
                        "%$searchQueryNoSpaces%"
                    ]
                );
        })
        // Parcels with these classification codes should not be searchable.
        ->whereNotIn('class_code', ['GR', 'MC', 'UT', 'MH', 'UTG&E', 'UTRR'])
        ->groupBy('complete_parcel_number', 'owners', 'full_site_address', 'class_code')
        ->orderBy('complete_parcel_number')
        ->paginate($per_page, ['*'], 'page', $page)
        ->withPath('parcels')
        ->appends(['query' => $searchQuery]);
```

'''

Comment: I don't think you need `distinct` here just add `\DB::raw('MAX(parcel_year)')` in your select and you'd get the max year in your result. `group by` will in practice produce distinct results in what is grouped

Comment: You are right on using the group by rather than the distinct. Adding '\DB::raw('MAX(parcel_year)') ' causes an error to be thrown, "Class 'DB' not found". I've tried adding "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;" to the beginning of that controller to no effect.

Comment: If you add the `use` then you don't need `\DB` you can use `DB`. If you still get "class not found" then something is probably going wrong. Maybe try running `composer dump-autoload` or something

Comment: @apokryfos As you said, changed to just DB. I encountered an error "A facade root has not been set." which led to me putting "use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;" instead of "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;". Also added "as max_year" to the DB::raw text to be able to refer to column on the site for display. This ended up working and I'm only seeing 1 row if the columns in the group by are the same. Thanks for the help.